# Modification of trade

Tags: online-trading

Previously asked some questions on *quant* about the type of structures I am trying to learn about. However, I found something **similar(not the same)** to what I actually want to ***trade*** and not just for the ***knowledge***. It is surprisingly available at **retail(With no $MM+ and other regulatory requirements).** I found it on Dukascopy(Regulated swiss broker and investment bank). Here is the link:
https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/binary-options/what-are-binary-options/touch-binaries/

All possible path scenarios are described towards the end of that webpage. The 3 possible scenarios are in the picture below:

[image: click here to see image]

Scenarios 1 and 2 are perfect, the only modification I want is at scenario 3. I want a ***loss*** in scenario 3 just the same as in scenario 2(instead of a refund of my initial investment). For that trade off I ***expect*** a much higher payout when scenario 1 occurs.

**Now my question are:**

Firstly, I would like to know if there are listed products(e.g structured notes) on any exchange that offer what I am looking for(since the banks and other bespoke issuers have no interest in doing business with the small guy)?

Secondly, why all the huge requirements from issuers, banks e.t.c if it’s legal and possible to have such a product at retail anyway?

*P.S: Dukascopy, also replied: “We don’t make such modifications for clients at this time”*

Comment: I developed a software for beginning Forex traders that suggests a trading structure of a limit order to take profit combined with a stop order to cut losses. Then Nadex introduced an option structure that they trademark as "Knock-outs". http://www.kbhscape.com/forexing.htm .

Comment: Ok thanks for that comment. However, I am not sure if you mean it’s not possible for me to find what I am looking for? @S Spring

Comment: With a continuous future, like Forex, the third scenario doesn't exist. Of course, Forex does relate to the contango and backwardation of traditional futures simply with the use of daily roll-over values. Or with an actual equity position the third scenario doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh, I see. The wording of the third scenario doesn't give a gain between break-even and the limit order but then also doesn't give a loss between break-even and the stop order. That's a little strange.

Comment: Yes, I want it to always be a loss even if it was close to the profit target before expiration, for scenario 3. So it has to be a structured product or exotic options provider that I guess that can provide that?

Answer (score 1):

The investor could make their own structure by opening the option position and then combining with a limit order for the possible profit and with a stop order for the possible loss. Then a standard options broker would furthermore trade the option to the advantage of the investor if it reached expiration.